# Как обновить локальный репозиторий git?

Tags: git, github

Как обновить локальный репозиторий git? Я сделал изменения на одном устройстве, запушил их на гитхаб и хочу посмотреть их на другом, как я могу обновить изменения?

Comment: на другом устройстве выполнить git pull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если на другом устройстве репозитория нет, то сделать git clone "ссылка на репозиторий по hhtp или ssh".

Если локальный репозиторий уже есть, то в самом репозитории открой терминал или git bash и напиши команду git pull